# Prepared Statement return wrong values

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I have a JAVA Application which uses HSQLDB. There is a table called 'marks' containing a column of integers called 'mark'. If I use the HSQLDB DatabaseManager to run the following query: SELECT AVG(CAST(mark as FLOAT)), SUM(mark) FROM marks WHERE sid=5 AND suid=8
The DBM returns the right values:
1.5 and 3; for marks 1 and 2.

If I use the following JAVA Code to read out this data with the same query, java always prints out 2. For the average and the sum. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.. Maybe you can help me.

```
        double avg = 0;
    PreparedStatement stmt = dbcn.prepareStatement("SELECT AVG(CAST(mark as FLOAT)), SUM(mark) FROM marks WHERE sid=? AND suid=?");
    stmt.setInt(1, 5);
    stmt.setInt(2, 8);
    ResultSet gARS = stmt.executeQuery();
    while(gARS.next()){
        avg = gARS.getDouble(1);
        System.out.println(gARS.getInt(2));
    }
    return avg;
```

Answer (score 1):

The System.out should print the SUM first: `3`.
Then the method returns avg, `1.5`. It seems that avg is printed rounded up.

Maybe you have something like:

```
double avg = callToDB(...);
System.out.printf("%10.0f", avg); // ERROR .0 should be at least .1
```

So inspect the format strings. If it was rounded down, it could have been an int cast.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I tried your suggestion but it still rounds up. I tried it with 2 x mark 1 and 1 x mark 2 now it says 1. :/

Comment: Ahh, I wanted to show the possible error, a format with 0 decimals resulting in a rounding. Just as happened now with 1 for 1.333.